How to export SVG without anti-aliasing?
Rationale
I expect that the title initially appears to be counterintuitive. However, I have been provided a QR code in BackerKit login settings (presumably of an otpauth: URI) which is solely provided in SVG format.
That is sensical, because it's rendered on an HTML page. However, no optical recognition method that I've evaluated has been able to interpret it.
Consequently, I want to utilize my go-to decoder, ZXing.org/w/decode.jspx. However, this requires that I submit the QR code as a standard bitmap image format (like JPEG or PNG) as its competing counterparts do.
Request
To convert the SVG to a useful image format, how can I have Inkscape export this to a bitmap format without converting the very straight lines into variable-opacity gradients, like the undermentioned screenshot demonstrates?

SVG in Inkscape:


PNG in Gwenview:



Example
As an example, I've included an unimportant section below (it's still a valid SVG file):
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" viewBox="0 0 627 627" shape-rendering="crispEdges" width="120" height="120"><rect width="11" height="11" x="0" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="11" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="22" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="33" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="44" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="55" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="66" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="110" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="121" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="154" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="165" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="220" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="286" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="308" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="319" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="352" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="374" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="418" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="440" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="462" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="484" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="506" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="517" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="550" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="561" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="572" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="583" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="594" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect><rect width="11" height="11" x="605" y="0" fill="#000" style="--darkreader-inline-fill: #e8e6e3;" data-darkreader-inline-fill=""></rect></svg>


Apologies if this isn't the correct forum. I wouldn't mind this being moved to SuperUser instead, for instance.

If nothing reads the code, then I'd suspect the code is bad. I can't read it here, even if I boost contrast. It's highly unlikely the vector format of an SVG is the issue. Vector is better not worse. I would try reading the code as it's presented on the creation site (I'm not singing up to test). If it can't be read there, then, yeah, the code isn't correct.

it's not interpolation you are referring to, It's anti-aliasing - but again.. you should want the SVG vector, not degrade it by converting it to a raster image. There is no reason a vector SVG code would be unreadable, but made readable by converting it to a raster image. The code should be readable either way and vector is better.

The initial link requires a login.

honestly if I was just testing using your decoder I'd just get a screenshot of the QR code and upload that, no need to waste time converting file formats and that image should be large enough to work.

@Scott and Luciano, I don't purport that the rendering format is at fault. I merely meant that I can't be certain that it indeed malformed until I parse it through an interpreter that can more reliably parse QR codes. This endeavour is indeed because I can't read it when it's rendered at the original URI, but that's not much of a confirmation since I'm using screenshots and photographs to convert it to a bitmap.

@Scott, the conversion in this case isn't a degradation. Because the original SVG is comprised entirely of squares of identical size, a bitmap representation can be 1:1, should the anti-aliasing be possible to disable.

@Rafael, that's because it's my TOTP code. However, if anyone happens to have an account there without TOTP 2FA configured, you'll see what I refer to.

@Scott, after using https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/166108/how-to-export-svg-without-anti-aliasing#comment252411_166110, the QR code was indeed readable. It appears that my camera wasn't able to capture it, nor were any optical interpreters acting on my screenshots, despite it being valid. I consider this thread to be a success. Thanks, all.

Can't you just open the SVG in your browser, and then take a screenshot of the screen section showing the QR code?

@Dreamer, I've already explained in this thread that that doesn't work. The representation of the squares on my display's pixel matrix isn't going to be 1:1.

It's impossible to render anything without antialiasing

@RokeJulianLockhart I see no requirement in your question that the representation needs to be 1:1, only that it needs to be recognizable by https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx . As such, any representation that's much larger than the QR code dot matrix should suffice. So, if your QR code is 57 by 57 dots then taking screenshot of it at e.g. 500 by 500 pixels and running that through your decoder should be perfectly fine.

@Dreamer, not in practice. To my knowledge, most QR decoders that aren't designed to function via a camera solely accept one pixel per data point, or at the most, an identical ratio. Were there a better interpreter, I wouldn't have needed to convert the SVG to a bitmap originally. I've tested about 10 decodersa to conclude this, but that's obviously not all of them.

@Fattie, I would like to say that that's untrue, but what are you referring to as "render" in this context? A conversion from SVG to a lossless bitmap format, like TIFF or PNG? If so, that's definitely untrue, as https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/166108/how-to-export-svg-without-anti-aliasing?noredirect=1#comment252411_166110 demonstrates. After all, the SVG references is merely a series of <rect>s.

Roke .. (I do not precisely understand what the OPs problem is but) .. if one has an image that is nothing but truly square'd off rectangles, and by an (impossible) coincidence every edge falls on a physical pixel, the end result will include anti-aliasing.  Remembering that nowadays we have absolutely no idea how many physical pixels there will be, what divisors will be involved, if the screen, anyway, antialiases even "hard horizontal/vertical edges" etc.

err, by OP I mean "you" :) :)

@RokeJulianLockhart for some reason, I'm getting very different results: I generated a simple QR code for http://example.com that is 25x25 dots in an image of 300x300 pixels. When I reduce its size to an arbitrary 35%, the dot edges get blurry due to interpolation. But uploading that blurry image to your proposed https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx still decodes the QR code's content perfectly fine.

@Dreamer, indeed. This is the sole time that it's failed for me, and I'm perplexed as to why. Considering that the original SVG representation wasn't working with my smartphone's camera either, I can't attest as to why without providing everyone here the TOTP key to my account. Thanks for the anecdote, though - I didn't test any blurry ones with that decoder.

@Fattie, regarding "I do not precisely understand what the OPs problem is", the problem I was experiencing was, summarily, a QR code that wouldn't be interpreted by my smartphone's camera, which I wanted to convert from its original SVG representation to a bitmap one, with no interpolation, which I didn't know how to do. Regarding the rest of your comment, surely you're merely referring to how a vector graphic is rendered on the display? I'm referring to converting a vector to a bitmap, which should be a fairly exact science if the vector is merely <rect>s.

R - "surely you're merely referring to how a vector graphic is rendered on the display".  Correct.  (I thought you meant, that when reading the result off a display, it didn't work.)  "I'm referring to converting a vector to a bitmap"  AH you are perfectly correct of course. That would be very handy an "SVG TO 0-1 BITMAP CONVERTOR" - !

if u're an ios programmer you can sort of do that with the trick of "filtering up" the size

@Fattie, thanks. Though, I'm (un)fortunately not an i(Pad)OS developer, since the barrier to entry for that ecosystem is incredibly high - I hear you can't even run XCode without macOS, and then you've got to pay approximately £100 per year to publish applications without a per-week-expiring development key. That's not the end of the world, but every macOS VM I've tried hasn't even been hardware accelerated...

lol all true @RokeJulianLockhart !!!

OK, here's what I can see from your screenshots.
The problem is anti-aliasing, and has nothing to do with interpolation. In this case, I think the cause of the anti-aliasing is that the number of pixels the image is being exported to is not a multiple of the number of squares in the QR code image.
I can see you have the export set to 120 x 120px but there are 57 x 57 squares in the image. I counted them. You should set the export dimensions to 57px, or multiples of 57, otherwise you will get anti-aliasing when exporting.
I also note the image you are showing only seems to be part of a QR code. I can't tell you if this will be readable. If you know what the data is supposed to be, Inkscape has a built-in QR code generator extension under Extensions > Render > Barcode/QR Code > QR Code. So, you could potentially just recreate it.

Unfortunately, converting the output size to 75 px still causes it to anti-alias, strangely: https://imgur.com/Usu6E9n. I also don't know what the data should be - as aforementioned, I'm trying to extract data from a QR code.

@RokeJulianLockhart 57, not 75.

Ha, that works. Thanks! I suppose I must count pixels in the future.

@RokeJulianLockhart Note that under normal circumstances when Inkscape generates a QR code using its own built-in QR code extension, the software generates the QR code at the correct scale, to correspond to the number of pixels (one square = one px). The correct dimensions will automatically show in the export dialog. But this is not necessarily the case for QR codes generated in other software. So you will almost certainly have to count those yourself.

you ought to be able to get away with exporting at a high resolution such that the (anti-aliasing due to the) scaling doesn't become too uneven - the difference between scaling one square 9x and the next 10x before anti-aliasing is applied is much less than with your scale of just over 2:1

@ChrisH, indeed, although in cases like this - where optical recognition has completely failed me - the ratio must be identical, because even a few variable-opacity pixels can be interpreted as invalid by a significant amount of parsers, whether standard-adherent or not...

@ChrisH - yes perhaps, however the OP specifically asked how to output a PNG of a QR Code without anti-aliasing using Inkscape. I consider this to be a perfectly reasonable request. It's easily done in Inkscape with the correct export settings.

@BillyKerr that's certainly true, and your answer was a clear enough one to the question (I had failed to +1 but have fixed that). I was considering the underlying issue
